# Can I pass a *reference* to an environment variable in a docker CMD?

Tags: docker, shell, amazon-ecs

I running a docker container through an ECS task, and attempting to override the Docker CMD in the Task Definition. I do not have control over the docker container, but by default it has an entrypoint of "/share/script.sh".

This entrypoint script, ultimately, invokes Chef Inspec (a compliance checking application) with arguments passed in from $@, like this:

```
inspec exec linux-baseline $@
```

When I pass in plaintext arguments by overriding CMD, everything is great. For example, passing in

```
CMD ["--backend","ssh"]
```

will result in

```
inspec exec linux-baseline --backend ssh
```

being executed.

What I would like to do is pass in a reference to a container environment variable via CMD (let's assume we know it's defined that $STACK=stack-name) - something like:

```
CMD ["--stack","${STACK}"]
```

where the executed code would be

```
inspec exec linux-baseline --stack stack-name
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is `${STACK}` an environment variable inside the container? Or is it something you want to pass when docker image is being run?/

Comment: It is an environment variable that is set on the container!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way might be to move this option into your startup script.  You can't do this with only `CMD` syntax.

If you're willing to part with the container-as-command pattern, you can achieve this by not having an `ENTRYPOINT` and using the string form of `CMD`:

```sh
# Reset ENTRYPOINT to empty
ENTRYPOINT []
CMD /share/script.sh --stack "${STACK}"
```

This also means you would need to include the script name if you override `CMD` in a `docker run` invocation or a Compose `command:`.

A similar option is to write your own wrapper script to be the new entrypoint that potentially fills in more options:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
exec /share/script.sh --stack "${STACK}" "$@"
```

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/new-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Docker never does environment variable expansion natively here.  Instead, the [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) directive has two forms:

1. If you use a JSON array `CMD ["--stack", "${STACK}"]` there is no interpolation or other processing; the command part is exactly the two words `--stack` `{STACK}`.
2. If you use anything else, Docker injects a shell to run the command, and that shell can do environment variable expansion; the command part is exactly the three words `sh`, `-c`, and the command string as a single word (quotes, punctuation, braces, and all).

In your case you can't use either form: the first form doesn't do the variable expansion, and the second form includes words `sh` and `-c` that your script won't understand.

Comment: Ahh, this is really really helpful. Thanks! For non-technical, organizational, stupid reasons, I "can't" change the Docker image itself, but I'm gonna lobby for them to let me make this change. I think ECS only lets you override CMD via the JSON format, which would mean the only way to do this based on what you're saying is by adding a new wrapper script as you mentioned. Great answer, thank you!